# Got error while starting with shopware app

Tags: doctrine-orm, shopware6, shopware6-app

I am new to shopware and symfony I am trying to develop an app by following this doc.
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/starter/product-translator.html.
After creating a new project using composer I tried `composer require shopware/app-bundle`
and got this error

```
The service "Shopware\App\SDK\Shop\ShopRepositoryInterface" has a dependency on a non-existent service "Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry"
```

I dont get a doctrine.yaml file created, I manually create one and this error gone and got another one

```
Cannot autowire service "Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\HttpMessageFactoryInterface": argument "$serverRequestFactory" of method "Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\PsrHttpFactory::__construct()" references  
   interface "Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestFactoryInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?
```

pasting my composer.json file here. What I missed?

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "shopware/app-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/console": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.3.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on Ubuntu 22.04 with php8.1. Following the steps of the documentation works for me. During the composer required, `symfony/flex` asks some questions. DId you say "yes" to all of them? The `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` is created for me. Can you try again in a empty folder and provide some information about your system.